# How does a transpiler like Babel implement tail call optimization when it is not supported inherently?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Even with trampoline/bind, an infinite recursion should hit memory/time higher for every iteration, so how does Babel implement this even when it is not supported currently?

Comment: Tail call optimisation doesn't prevent infinite time for infinite loops either :-) It just prevents the stack from growing.

Comment: Indeed, my question was exactly on the stack build up. In fn languages the compiler does the trick and optimizes so it can recurse without using stack frames, i was wondering how it is done when the compiler does not inherently supports it out of the box.

Comment: Well, in that case babel can do the work for the compiler - that's what a transpiler is for :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel tries to rewrite the recursion as a simple loop, you can see that in [the example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20factorial(n%2C%20acc%20%3D%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22use%20strict%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(n%20%3C%3D%201)%20return%20acc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20factorial(n%20-%201%2C%20n%20*%20acc)%3B%0A%7D) they give in the documentation:

```
function factorial(n, acc = 1) {
    "use strict";
    if (n <= 1) return acc;
    return factorial(n - 1, n * acc);
}
```

gets rewritten as

```
"use strict";

function factorial(_x2) {
    var _arguments = arguments;
    var _again = true;

    _function: while (_again) {
        var n = _x2;
        acc = undefined;

        "use strict";
        _again = false;
        var acc = _arguments[1] === undefined ? 1 : _arguments[1];
        if (n <= 1) return acc;
        _arguments = [_x2 = n - 1, n * acc];
        _again = true;
        continue _function;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm continue (which is essentially a goto) helps avoid the stack build up? (I am a newbie to JS world and not sure if continue is actually a goto like)

Comment: No, the continue is not needed for that (they introduced that to [improve performance](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/736), but I'm not quite sure how it helps). A simple loop is all thats needed, because the function doesn't get called multiple times now and so doesn't increase the size of the callstack.

Comment: Beats me, if we do not use continue and just do _function() would it not recurse but without tail call and cause stack frames to blow up?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20a%20%3D%20(n)%3D%3E%20a(n%2B1)

It rewrites it into a while loop.